# How to print following text on new line every pair?

Tags: python

I have text which I want to show on newlines:

```
strname='A->1 B->2 C->1 Z->4'
```

Expected output:

```
A->1
B->2
C->1
Z->4
```

When I used `end=`, it does not give any output:

```
strname='A->1 B->2 C->1 Z->4'
output= (strname, end='\n')
```

Comment: Split it on " " and rejoin it with "\n" ~ `output = '\n'.join(strname.split(' '))`. `replace` would also work ~ `output = strname.replace(' ', '\n')`

Comment: `output= (strname,end='\n')` is not valid syntax. What did you expect this to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace()`:

```py
strname = 'A->1 B->2 C->1 Z->4'
output = strname.replace(' ', '\n')
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
A->1
B->2
C->1
Z->4
```